# Can I use XForms to ask the user to create an arbitrary length list and then collect attributes about each list item?

Tags: xml, xforms, wxformbuilder

For a field data collection project, can someone provide a pointer on how I may be able to create a form like this:

1. First, collect a list of people at a location. The number of people may be variable.
2. Once the list is complete, then for each person in the list collect age and gender and several other fixed/known attributes by present.

How do I create a loop such that the form reader iterates in step 2 above over each item collected in item 1.

A small XML snippet will be appreciated. I am stuck at how to create the loop for the second item.

I intend to use this with Open Data Kit (ODK)

Answer (score 1):

Because the length of the list could be arbitrary, the best way to handle this is probably to have a button or other indicator by which YOU determine that the first loop should terminate and the second loop should begin.

Secondly, you should be careful to separate the responsibilities of your GUI from your actual program. The GUI should be very dumb and should do little more than get input.

Your actual program (perhaps just a different class that invokes your GUI), should then be able to get whatever it needs, and send whatever it wants shown, from/to the GUI.

If you want to use loops, you'd have a loop that gets a name (or whatever else you want to use to identify a single person) from your GUI, if a new one is available. Then you have the GUI tell the app to break that loop (a button that calls a function, or sets a value, etc), and the app moves on to the second loop.

What I'd recommend, though, is a "save" button. There's no need to loop, just set up an event handler that calls something like "append_new_name_to_the_list(new_name)" every time you click "save." Then have one "save" for names, and another "save" for extra data. You'd have to figure out how to determine which name goes with which extra info, but that could be as simple as just starting at the beginning of the list and keeping track of that position.

Obviously, if you can collect ALL the information at once, that'd be even easier, but I realize that might not be desirable.